# How can change font size on dot matrix report?

Tags: .net, windows, printing

I want to design a double layer payslip and print on dot matrix printer.

How can change font size on dot matrix report?

If dor matrix report can't be change font size, and I change to standard report, but the printing speed is very slow, how can I solved?I want to design a double layer payslip and print on dot matrix printer.

How can change font size on dot matrix report?

i assume dot matrix report can't be change font size, and I change to standard report, but the printing speed is very slow,

how can I solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dot matrix printer in text mode, you need to send the printer specific control commands to change the font size etc. These are different for every make of printer, and even slightly between different models of the same make. An example would be [ESC P codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P) for Epson dot matrix printers.

Make sure to reset the settings to the default settings using the specific command for this purpose at the start and end of you print job, so you start from a defined starting point, and you are nice to the next print job that might not be so clever and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You make a dot-matrix printer fast by [bypassing the driver](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) for it.  The driver will use the graphics mode of the printer, works well for the kind of output generated by Windows programs but is *very* slow.  You will however now need to send the native print commands to the printer for special effects, usually control characters or escape sequences.  Font size support tend to be limited, usually just double-height.  But that really depends on the specific printer.

To learn what to send to the printer you will need to obtain the programming manual from the vendor.